# Report Builder - Check condition with multiple values using switch

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Is there a way to use switch , in report builder, to check for multiple values?

`**I can do** :

```
Switch(
       Fields!parentclass.Value = 522,(Fields!Score.Value/21),
       Fields!parentclass.Value =4602,(Fields!Score.Value/2)
)
```

**I want to do**

```
Switch(
       Fields!parentclass.Value = 522,(Fields!Score.Value/21),
       Fields!parentclass.Value =4602,(Fields!Score.Value/2),
       Fields!parentclass.Value ="3969,3967,586,3968",(Fields!Score.Value/22)
)
```

Is it even possible to do so without using multiple "OR".

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for editing @alejandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Switch(
Fields!parentclass.Value = 522,(Fields!Score.Value/21),
Fields!parentclass.Value =4602,(Fields!Score.Value/2),
Array.IndexOf(Split("3969,3967,586,3968",","),CStr(Fields!parentclass.Value))>=0,(Fields!Score.Value/22)
)
```

Let me know if this helps you.